# JSON empty array entry disappeared

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I defined a JSON, and post it to back end (Node.js).

```
var imj = {};
imj.images = [];
$.post("/image/uploadImages", imj, function(feedback){
.....
```

However, what the backend received was

```
{}
```

the "images" entry disappeared.

Here's the backend code:

```
exports.uploadImages = function(req, res) {
    if (typeof req.body.images == 'undefined') {
        return res.json({
            code: 1,
            message: "parameter incomplete"
        })
    }
    .....
```

So the backend return the error {code:1, message:'parameter incomplete'}

Anyone knows why? If I want the backend to receive this empty array, what should I do?

Comment: It seems like you are posting, images as empty array, `img.images = []`. Is there a reason behind it? That may be reason its empty because i dont see you assigning any images to the array in the code.

Comment: @JeremyRajan I want to upload images, but sometimes user does not upload images. For code neatness, I upload it no matter users upload images or not.

Comment: @KingstonChan, could you post a fiddle, for us to inspect?

Comment: What is the backend code handling the response?

Comment: @Moogs I have edited the question, part of the backend code and it's response are added

Comment: @JeremyRajan The problem is that what the frontend posted and what the backend received are not the same thing. I don't think fiddle can display the problem to you

Answer (score 0):

What's the `contentType` nodeJS is expecting on the back-end?  The default `contentType` for the `$.post` method is *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*.  If you're endpoint is looking for *application/json*, you'll always see an empty input.

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` sends url encoded data, so you need to use `$.ajax` and specify the content type as well as JSON stringify the data.

```
var data = {};
data.images = [];

$.ajax({
    url: '/image/uploadImages', 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data); // { images: [] }
});
```

On the server side make sure to use a body parser.

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body); // { images: [] }
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this method, but my backend also received {}. And I also tried isPlainObject, I found imj is PlainObject. Do you know why?

Comment: @KingstonChan are you using express? if so are you using `body-parser`? http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body

Comment: Yes, I'm using express and body-parser.
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }));

Comment: @KingstonChan I think you need `app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json`

Comment: I used both bodyParser.json and bodyParser.urlencoded, but still the same problem. It's strange...

Comment: @KingstonChan I got it to work by `JSON.stringify`ing the data. Updated answer